# Unable to get celery running, getting error celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I am unable to get celery running, not sure what i am doing wrong. I installed Celery along with RabbitMQ libraries. My rabbitmq is running on port 5672. I have defined it as follows

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I then run my worker by using the below command

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

But when i do the below, then i get the error message. It's a simple basic example and it should run without any issues but still not able to get it running.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 17:36:57)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4, 4)
>>> result.ready()
False
>>> result.get(timeout=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 16                                                                 9, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py",                                                                  line 157, in wait_for
    raise TimeoutError('The operation timed out.')
celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out.
```

Comment: is your worker actually running? Also, did you define your celery app somewhere in tasks?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `app.backend.get_result(result.id)`